# Sublime text 3 misinterpreting indentation when code is pasted

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Love Sublime text, though I have come across an issue which seems to be an inconsistent issue when copying code. I used `tab` for indentation, and when I need to copy over code, it seems to attempt to interpret the tabs as spaces, but results in sending the indentation wonky.

I know you can go into settings, so I did, and change the values for properties such as `tab_size`, `translate_tabs_to_spaces`, but nothing seems to prevent it from happening. Instead of being 4 spaces for indentation, the lines are only one space, and when I hit `tab` it moves it one space.

***Question***

How do I force Sublime to only use `tab` for indentation which is currently set to `4` spaces everytime I create a new document?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't tell us how you are pasting the code so I am assuming you are doing a simple paste rather than the Sublime Text way with <kbd>Shift</kbd> :

> Sublime’s Paste and Indent command fixes this by automatically adjusting the indentation of your pasted code to match the surrounding lines.
>
> This command is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on Windows and Linux or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on Mac. Give it a try—it’s magical.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It doesn't properly indent according to the Tab Width setting.

Comment: Hard to tell from your “it doesn’t work” report but it sounds like it is working exactly as intended.

Comment: while it automatically paste to match the surrounding codes, it does not match the indent tab width. For example: https://i.imgur.com/WbnxuB1.png . The code in the red box is pasted (ctrl+shift+v) from somewhere else with tab width of 2, while the other surrounding codes have a tab width of 4. I'm assuming if it actually works, it would match the codes with tab width of 4.

Comment: To clarify what I mean by 'match the surrounding codes', with normal `ctrl + v`, it would look like this: https://i.imgur.com/LRmmtH8.png .

Comment: Interesting. I am a believer in the “spaces not tabs” thought technology so haven’t run into this. If you set your ST options to ‘Tabs as spaces’ before the paste do you have more luck?

Comment: I am indenting as space, specifically the setting 'Indent using Spaces', and I always make sure to convert indentations to spaces via the menu.

Comment: Sounds like you might have discovered a reportable bug.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is too late to answer but alternatively for @jwpfox answer, you can switch it in keybindings like so:

```
{ "keys": ["super+shift+v"], "command": "paste" },
{ "keys": ["super+v"], "command": "paste_and_indent" },
```

You can switch these 2 keybindings if you want to use the `paste and indent` by default.